# Boolean logic with BITs and Booleans in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database, bitwise-comparison

How can I mix boolean logic with bitwise and/or operators in SQL Server, specifically SQL Azure Database and/or SQL Server 2016?

To demonstrate what I'm trying to do, consider the following script:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(2000) = 'asdf'
DECLARE @Flag1 bit = 1
DECLARE @Flag2 bit = 0

DECLARE @Data Table
(
    Value bit
)

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (@Flag1 | @Flag2)
--INSERT INTO @Data VALUES ((@Flag1 | @String LIKE '%qwerty%') & @Flag2)
SELECT * FROM @Data
```

The script works fine as-is but the moment you uncomment out that second `INSERT`, all hell breaks loose. I understand this is invalid syntax because I'm mixing boolean logic with bitwise operators. But what is the right way to get this logic in there? Without going crazy with `CASE WHEN` statements, is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to revise your code as follows:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(2000) = 'asdf'
DECLARE @Flag1 bit = 1
DECLARE @Flag2 bit = 0

DECLARE @Data Table
(
    Value bit
)

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (@Flag1 | @Flag2)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES ((@Flag1 | case when charindex('qwerty', @string ) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) & @Flag2)
SELECT * FROM @Data
```

Your original code has syntax error because [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is not an operator.

Another way is to use [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) as following

```
DECLARE @String varchar(2000) = 'asdf'
DECLARE @Flag1 bit = 1
DECLARE @Flag2 bit = 0

DECLARE @Data Table
(
    Value bit
)

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (@Flag1 | @Flag2)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES ((@Flag1 | iif( @String LIKE '%qwerty%', 1, 0)) & @Flag2)
SELECT * FROM @Data
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I like the IIF solution best of the two.